# I need to calculate month-on-month change and change in same month last year from a table fetched from SQL database using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pymssql

Here how the departure table should look like and the headers:

| Report_Month | Aircraft_Departures(Domestic) | Aircraft_Departures(International) | MOM Change(domestic) | MOM Change(international) | change_SMLY(Domestic) | change_SMLY(International) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Here is the code which I have written to get this table from SQL as pivot table.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql
import numpy as np
conn = pymssql.connect('database-1.cmtpadv1tggf.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com','OPERATIONSDBOWNER','OPERATIONSDBOWNER@4321','ForOperationsData')
s ='''SELECT * FROM [ForOperationsData].[dbo].[IN_Monthly_DGCA_Airline_Traffic]'''
df = pd.read_sql(s, conn)
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Report_Month', columns='Airline_Service', values='Aircraft_Departures', aggfunc=np.sum)
df1.sort_values(by = 'Report_Month', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df1.rename(columns = {'Report_Month':'Months','Domestic':'Aircraft_Departures(Domestic)','International':'Aircraft_Departures(International)'}, inplace = True)
df1['index'] = df1.index
first_column = df1.pop('index')
df1.insert(0, 'index', first_column)
cols = ['Aircraft_Departures(Domestic)','Aircraft_Departures(International)']
df1['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['index'], dayfirst=True)
df3 = df1.set_index('index')[cols]
print(df1)
d = {'Aircraft_Departures(Domestic)':'(Domestic)','Aircraft_Departures(International)':'(International)'}
df1 = df3.shift(1, freq='MS')
df2 = df3.shift(12, freq='MS')
df4 = df3.shift(36, freq='MS')#pre covid for year 2022
df11 = df3.sub(df1).div(df1).rename(columns=d).add_prefix('MOM Change')
df22 = df3.sub(df2).div(df2).rename(columns=d).add_prefix('change_SMLY')
df44 = df3.sub(df4).div(df4).rename(columns=d).add_prefix('change Pre-Covid')
df3 = pd.concat([df3, df11.reindex(df3.index), df22.reindex(df3.index), df44.reindex(df3.index)], axis=1)
df3.to_excel("Social media script", sheet_name='Ratio')
```

formula for m-o-m and y-o-y will be calculated by
MOM Change = (Departure this month - Departure previous month)/Departure previous month
change_SMLY = (Departure current month - Departure same month last year)/Departure same month last year    change_Pre-covid = (Departure current month - Departure same month in 2019)/Departure same month in 2019

I have calculated 'change_pre-covid ' for the year 2022 as an example.

Help me in getting those values for the years 2021 and 2020 as well

Comment: Can you add some sample data with expected ouput to question? [How to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I have added sample output in the image link to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create DatetimeIndex first, then use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) by one and 12 months, subtract and divide and last join all DataFrames together:

```
cols = ['Aircraft_Departures(Domestic)','Aircraft_Departures(International)']

df1['Report_Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Report_Month'], dayfirst=True)
df = df1.set_index('Report_Month')[cols]

d = {'Aircraft_Departures(Domestic)':'(International)',
     'Aircraft_Departures(International)':'(domestic)'}

df1 = df.shift(1, freq='MS')
df2 = df.shift(12, freq='MS')
df11 = df.sub(df1).div(df1).rename(columns=d).add_prefix('MOM Change')
df22 = df.sub(df2).div(df2).rename(columns=d).add_prefix('change_SMLY')

df = pd.concat([df, df11.reindex(df.index), df22.reindex(df.index)], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)

          Aircraft_Departures(Domestic)  \
Report_Month                                  
2022-06-01                            39482   
2022-05-01                            87224   
2022-04-01                            82701   
2022-03-01                            81971   
2022-02-01                            58153   
2022-01-01                            64437   
2021-12-01                            88270   
2021-11-01                            82614   
2021-10-01                            74137   
2021-09-01                            66580   
2021-08-01                            63108   
2021-07-01                            51402   
2021-06-01                            34318   

              Aircraft_Departures(International)  MOM Change(International)  \
Report_Month                                                                  
2022-06-01                                  7896                  -0.547349   
2022-05-01                                 12220                   0.054691   
2022-04-01                                 10641                   0.008906   
2022-03-01                                 10636                   0.409575   
2022-02-01                                  8396                  -0.097522   
2022-01-01                                  9826                  -0.270001   
2021-12-01                                  9599                   0.068463   
2021-11-01                                  8526                   0.114342   
2021-10-01                                  8475                   0.113503   
2021-09-01                                  7281                   0.055017   
2021-08-01                                  5756                   0.227734   
2021-07-01                                  4252                   0.497815   
2021-06-01                                  3311                        NaN   

              MOM Change(domestic)  change_SMLY(International)  \
Report_Month                                                     
2022-06-01               -0.353846                    0.150475   
2022-05-01                0.148388                         NaN   
2022-04-01                0.000470                         NaN   
2022-03-01                0.266794                         NaN   
2022-02-01               -0.145532                         NaN   
2022-01-01                0.023648                         NaN   
2021-12-01                0.125850                         NaN   
2021-11-01                0.006018                         NaN   
2021-10-01                0.163988                         NaN   
2021-09-01                0.264941                         NaN   
2021-08-01                0.353716                         NaN   
2021-07-01                0.284204                         NaN   
2021-06-01                     NaN                         NaN   

              change_SMLY(domestic)  
Report_Month                         
2022-06-01                 1.384778  
2022-05-01                      NaN  
2022-04-01                      NaN  
2022-03-01                      NaN  
2022-02-01                      NaN  
2022-01-01                      NaN  
2021-12-01                      NaN  
2021-11-01                      NaN  
2021-10-01                      NaN  
2021-09-01                      NaN  
2021-08-01                      NaN  
2021-07-01                      NaN  
2021-06-01                      NaN
```

Comment: I need to get data for one more column which will be month vs same month pre-covid, which will certainly mean from the year 2019. I have edited the question for the reference and did it for the year 2022 but I need to do the same for the years 2021 and 2020. Please help me in getting the numbers for 2021 and 2020 in the pre-covid column

Comment: df4 = df3.shift(36, freq='MS')    df44 = df3.sub(df4).div(df4).rename(columns=d).add_prefix('change Pre-Covid')    df3 = pd.concat([df3, df11.reindex(df3.index), df22.reindex(df3.index), df44.reindex(df3.index)], axis=1) it works and gives the value for 2022 but i need the same for the year 2021 and 2020 as well.